# How to increment value of a counter by clicking on a button?

Tags: r, gwidgets

I have a button like this :

```
win <- gwindow("Extraction des mots clés", visible=TRUE)
obj2 <- gbutton("Valider et afficher les mots suivants",container=win)
```

I want that each time I press the button, a counter which is set to 0 in my script is incremented.

`k<-0`

I created this handler :

```
addHandlerClicked(obj2,handler = function(h,...){
k<-k+1
print (k)
return(k)
})
```

but when I do`print k` outside of the `addHandlerClicked`, `k`is still 0. So how can I do ? Moreover, is the instruction `return (k)`that I wrote above can be used to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you need `<<-` or perhaps you need to write to a database (like sqlite).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Could you help me on how to use `<<-` ? Because making a database only to increment a counter is maybe a bit hard way

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks it works ! Could you please post it as answer so that other people could benefit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way R functions work. Objects in (global) workspace have one value and when you create a same-name object within a function, it has no memory of the same name object outside. R functions don't modify other variables, you have to return the modified value and overwrite it explictily. Normally. Enter `<<-`. This assignment operator will go from the function all the way to the global environment and try to find the same name object and write over/to it. See more info by typing `?"<<-"`.